# Python: What is the difference between `lambda` and `lambda_`?

Tags: python

I know the function of `lambda:` and `lambda var:` , but what does `lambda_:` means acutally?

Comment: Yeah, I just tried it. Tokenization doesn't work like I thought, apparently. This is why I try to use whitespace in a sane way.

Comment: If you saw this somewhere like `def foo(lambda_: Callable): …`, that means the author tried to use the word “lambda” to mean “callback function”, but had to append the underscore for it not to be a syntax error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lambda_` is just a variable name, like any other. Like `foo` or `x`.

If you saw:

```
lambda_: Something
```

Then that is actually a *variable annotation*, for type hints, so the same as:

```
num: int
num = 0
```

Comment: Interestingly, ```num: print("Hello")``` evaluates the righthand side of the expression. But ```a = num:print("Hello")``` fails with syntax error. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @MuslimbekAbduganiev an annotation cannot be on the right hand side of an equals sign, so `x = y: int` would raise a syntax error, you'd need `x: int = y`

Answer (score -3):

`lambda:` means `lambda` method doesn't take any argument

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

def caller(var):
    var()


caller(lambda : print("OP"))
```

`lambda var`: means method is taking `var` as **argument**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

def caller(var,arg):
    var(arg)


foo = lambda x: print(x)
caller(foo, "OP")
```

`lambda _:` here **_** is an argument

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.10

def caller(var,__):
    var(__)


foo = lambda _ : print(_)
caller(foo, "OP")
```

output for all above program is **OP**

Comment: there is no space between `lambda` and` _` ..

Comment: ```lambda_``` is a variable name. ```a = lambda :print("Hello")``` will execute properly, but ```a = lambda_:print("Hello")``` will fail with syntax error. What you mean is probably ```lambda _:```